# VSCode does not see Net Framework

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, .net-framework-version

I use VSCode for Unity 2021.3.9f1. When running VSCode it throws an error.I have it installed Net Framework 4.7.1 dev and sdk 6.0.400 and Framework 4.8 and 3.5.

Starting OmniSharp server at 15.09.2022, 09:27:31
Target: c:\Users\TheDe\Yatopia

OmniSharp server started with .NET 6.0.400
.
Path: c:\Users\TheDe.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-win32-x64.omnisharp\1.39.0-net6.0\OmniSharp.dll
PID: 11032

Starting OmniSharp on Windows 10.0.19044.0 (x64)
info: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
Checking the 'DOTNET_ROOT' environment variable to find a .NET SDK
info: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
Using the 'dotnet' on the PATH.
info: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
DotNetPath set to dotnet
info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
1: .NET Core SDK 6.0.400 17.3.0 - "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400"
info: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
Registered MSBuild instance: .NET Core SDK 6.0.400 17.3.0 - "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400"
info: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitialize
warn: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\TheDe\Yatopia\Unity.VisualScripting.Shared.Editor.csproj'.
c:\Users\TheDe\Yatopia\Unity.VisualScripting.Shared.Editor.csproj
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): Error: не найдены ссылочные сборки для .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1. Чтобы устранить эту проблему, установите пакет разработчика (пакет SDK или пакет нацеливания) для этой версии платформы или перенацельте приложение. Пакеты разработчика для платформы .NET Framework можно скачать на странице https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks.

Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\TheDe\Yatopia\UnityEngine.TestRunner.csproj

Inlay hints requested for document not in workspace Location { FileName = c:\Users\TheDe\Yatopia\Assets\NewBehaviourScript.cs, Range = Range { Start = Point { Line = 0, Column = 0 }, End = Point { Line = 18, Column = 0 } } }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like OmniSharp is using .NET 6.
You want to install .NET 6 on your machine.

You can download .NET 6 [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)

Also note that if you use a .NET 6 package in your .NET Framework project, it will not work and you'll need to migrate to .NET 6 or need a .NET Framework compatible version.

Answer (score -1):

c# plugin, settings, userModenDotnt = false.